# Design pattern to model transactions

Tags: design-patterns, transactions

There is a set of tasks I need to execute as an atomic transaction. i.e while executing the tasks, if any task fails, I need to revert the changes done during the previous tasks and exit without executing the subsequent tasks. This is similar to how DB transactions are handled. Is there a well known design pattern to address this case ?

P.S. I tried to search on internet but got a bunch of research papers, since the question must be common to most of the systems, I m just checking whether there is a known recommended method to solve this problem.

Comment: You might want to look at [STM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_transactional_memory).

Answer (score 0):

The simplest technique is "lock and log", as I like to call it. Acquire locks around resources being modified to prevent concurrent modification, and log compensating actions for every change being made.

The locks should be acquired at whatever granularity level is easiest to implement, or at the level which achieves the desired level of concurrency. A global lock is sufficient in most cases where "it just works" is the most important goal.

A compensating action is the opposite of the change which was made. If a record was deleted, then the compensating action is an insert which brings the record back to life. It can be considered an "undelete" action. The purpose of the locks is to ensure that the compensating actions don't interfere with anything else.

An alternative approach involves multiversion concurrency control, or MVCC. Rather than making changes immediately, and then applying compensating actions for rollback, keep a log of changes that should be applied atomically when the transaction is committed. A rollback simply discards the log. One downside to this approach is optimistic lock failure, and another downside is that you cannot "read your writes", unless the log of changes is also examined.